# Flot graph not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am trying to generate a graph using Flot library.

```
var d= [ [1293840000000,332],[1293926400000,321],[1294012800000,310],[1294099200000,299],[1294185600000,288],[1294272000000,277],[1294358400000,266],[1294444800000,255],[1294531200000,244],[1294617600000,233],[1294704000000,222],[1294790400000,211],[1294876800000,200],[1294963200000,189],[1295049600000,178],[1295136000000,167],[1295222400000,156],[1295308800000,145],[1295395200000,134],[1295481600000,123],[1295568000000,112],[1295654400000,101],[1295740800000,90],[1295827200000,79],[1295913600000,68],[1296000000000,57],[1296086400000,46],[1296172800000,35],[1296259200000,24],[1296345600000,13]];

$.plot($("#placeholder"), [d], { xaxis: { mode: "time" } });
```

The above generates the graph. But when I have the data contained in `d[]` in a variable and I try using

```
var d=[formateddata3];
```

Where formatteddata3 has

```
[1293840000000,332],[1293926400000,321],[1294012800000,310],[1294099200000,299],
[1294185600000,288],[1294272000000,277],[1294358400000,266],[1294444800000,255],
[1294531200000,244],[1294617600000,233],[1294704000000,222],[1294790400000,211],
[1294876800000,200],[1294963200000,189],[1295049600000,178],[1295136000000,167],
[1295222400000,156],[1295308800000,145],[1295395200000,134],[1295481600000,123],
[1295568000000,112],[1295654400000,101],[1295740800000,90],[1295827200000,79],
[1295913600000,68],[1296000000000,57],[1296086400000,46],[1296172800000,35],
[1296259200000,24],[1296345600000,13]
```

The issue I'm thinking of is passing the value from the variable into the array. 
I am building this `formateddata3` using for a loop. Hopefully someone can help me with the right way of doing it

Also when i alert d with with values (ie one without passing the variable) i get

```
1293840000000,332,1293926400000,321,1294012800000,310,1294099200000,299,
1294185600000,288
```

whereas when i alert with the vairable passed i get

```
[1293840000000,332],[1293926400000,310],[1294012800000,288]
```

The first one generates the graph...

//here is full code as asked

```
var d1=[{!formateddata1}];
var d2=[{!formateddata2}];
var start = new Date(document.getElementById('Stardate').value);
var end= new Date(document.getElementById('CompleteDate').value);
var noofdays=datediff(start ,end,'days') ;
var hours= document.getElementById('page1:form2:amount').value ; 
var totalhours= {!est_project_hours};
var formateddata3='';
var cumhours=0;

for (var i=0;i<noofdays;i++)
{

 if (i==0)
 {
 cumhours=totalhours;

 formateddata3='['+start.getTime()+ ','+cumhours+'],[';
 alert(formateddata3);
 }
 else if(i==noofdays-1)
 {
 start.setDate(start.getDate()+1);
cumhours=cumhours-hours;

 formateddata3=formateddata3+start.getTime()+ ','+cumhours+']';


  }
  else
  {
  start.setDate(start.getDate()+1);
  cumhours=cumhours-hours;

  formateddata3=formateddata3+start.getTime()+ ','+cumhours+'],['
  }

  }   
   // when i use the d3 with these values the graph works  
  //var d3=[ [1293840000000,332],[1293926400000,321],[1294012800000,310],     [1294099200000,299],[1294185600000,288],[1294272000000,277],[1294358400000,266],[1294444800000,255],[1294531200000,244],[1294617600000,233],[1294704000000,222],[1294790400000,211],[1294876800000,200],[1294963200000,189],[1295049600000,178],[1295136000000,167],[1295222400000,156],[1295308800000,145],[1295395200000,134],[1295481600000,123],[1295568000000,112],[1295654400000,101],[1295740800000,90],[1295827200000,79],[1295913600000,68],[1296000000000,57],[1296086400000,46],[1296172800000,35],[1296259200000,24],[1296345600000,13]];
  //alert([formateddata3]);
  var d3=[];
  var d3=[formateddata3];// but when i use it like this it doesnt work
  alert('d3 value is '+d3);
  alert('d1 value is '+d1);
  alert('d2 value is '+d2);
  j$.plot(j$("#placeholder"),[ { label: "Timelog", data:d1 },{ label: "Avg", data:d2   },{ label: "Simulated", data:d3}],
 {
 series: {
 lines: { show: true },
 points: { show: true }
 },


 xaxis:
  { mode: "time",
  min: {!startdate},
   max: {!enddate}
  }
  ,yaxis: {
  min:0, tickSize: 5
  }

  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

It seems you're building your formateddata3 as a string. flot expects a javascript array.

```
var formateddata3 = new Array();

for (var i=0;i<noofdays;i++)
{
   if (i==0)
   {
      cumhours=totalhours;
   }
   else if(i==noofdays-1)
   {
      start.setDate(start.getDate()+1);
      cumhours=cumhours-hours;
   }
   else
   {
      start.setDate(start.getDate()+1);
      cumhours=cumhours-hours;
   }
   formateddata3.push(new Array(start.getTime(), cumhours));
}
```

Just pass formateddata3 directly to flot then.

Comment: That didnt work... tried passing [formateddata3] directly into the graph... when i do a alert of d with the values rather than the variable name the alert displays d3 value is 1293840000000,332,1293926400000,321,1294012800000,310,1294099200000,299,1294185600000,288,1294272000000,277,1294358400000,266 but when i alert with the value passed as variable name then i get [1293840000000,332],[1293926400000,310],[1294012800000,288],[1294099200000,266]

Comment: @Prady I'm not sure what exactly you are doing, but this example does work http://jsfiddle.net/LDnUQ/ Maybe you can show more code.

Comment: added  the updated  code, all the vars with {!variable} is got from salesforce server.

Comment: Thanks... passing as a string was the issue... passing as an array solved the problem.... thanks a ton